# Yodlee: Instant Account Verification API

Tags: yodlee

In looking through the IAV API docs, I see that the user also has to register an account before being able to query financial data on the user. Is the user account unique to Yodlee or is it unique to each cobrand? How are other companies implementing the IAV flow? Is the cobrand creating the user account and managing it for the user? Or is there an API flow with a modal window that the user registers an account themselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how Yodlee works in terms of IAV or Aggregation.

1. A cobrand is created for each company who connects with yodlee and
   use it's APIs.
2. Now if the cobrand wants do IAV or aggregation for
   their users then they have to register each and every user on Yodlee
   platform.
3. Once registered these users can do IAV or aggregation
   based    on the cobrand's implementation.

Hence registration of a user is a mandetory procedure so that each user has access to only their accounts which they have linked.
Now these user accounts are unique to a cobrand. Implementing the IAV flow is completely dependent on the cobrands.
There are two types of IAV flows -

1. IAV data service flow - In this Yodlee returns the account level data and clients implement their own logic to match the account.
2. IAV matching service flow - In this Yodlee does matching using the predefined business logic of Yodlee.

For registering a user there is an API but no modal window provided by yodlee for registering a user. 
Hence cobrand can choose any of the below approach -

1. Show user a registration window and let them register directly on
   Yodlee
2. Let user register on your application and use the same to
   register on yodlee
3. Let user register on your application and then you create a account for user with different login on yodlee and manage the mapping at your end.